# Setting `iframe src` not working through scope but works by hard coded - how to solve this?

Tags: angularjs, iframe

I am getting `iframe` url from server. after i receive that, i am setting to `iframe' as like this:

```
<iframe ng-src="{{video}}" frameborder="0"></iframe> //without quote
```

But not working at all. in case if I hard-code the same value it's working fine. even i have tried like this:

```
<div class="content">

        {{video}} //i am getting path correctly

        <iframe ng-src="{{'video'}}" frameborder="0"></iframe>


    </div>
```

what is the issue here?

I am gettting this error :

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$interpolate/interr?p0=%7B%7Bvideo%7D%7D&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24sce%3Ainsecurl%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.9%2F%24sce%2Finsecurl%3Fp0%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flivecam.mktimelapse.com%252Fkhalifa-stadium2

Comment: what's in the video ? please provide the path

Comment: actually this is not direct video. I am getting `iframe` url. the `iframe` has the vide. ( http://livecam.mktimelapse.com/khalifa-stadium2 ) - it wont work for you

Comment: Try like this `<iframe ng-src="video" frameborder="0"></iframe>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of security policy imposed from angular 1.2.

Try to make your link trustable

Like this

add module `ngSanitize`

```
var app=angular.module("app", ['ngSanitize']);
```

then inject `$sce` in your controller

```
function MyController($scope,$sce) {
```

Then make your link trustable

```
$sce.trustAsResourceUrl(video);
```

<kbd>`DEMO`</kbd>

Comment: But still i am getting this error : https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=ngSanitizeProvider%20%3C-%20ngSanitize%20%3C-%20projectSummaryController

Comment: did you inject this [library](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular-sanitize.min.js) ? @3gwebtrain please check the demo's externarl resources .